# Cassandra sometimes skips records in SELECT query

Tags: cassandra

My setup is:

- cassandra 1.2.19
- single datacenter cluster with 4 nodes
- NetworkTopologyStrategy with replication factor of 3
- consistency level of writes to the db is set to `LOCAL_QUORUM`

I am trying to iterate all records in a given table and I do so with some legacy application code which fetches the data in batches with consecutive select queries of this type:

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE TOKEN(partition_key) > last_partition_key_of_previous_batch LIMIT 1000;
```

The problem is that sometimes some records are skipped. I also noticed that those skipped records are old, added months ago to the database.

All of the select queries are executed with consistency level `ONE`.

Is it possible that this is the cause?

From what I understood about consistency levels when the consistency level for reads is `ONE`, only one node is asked to execute the query.

Is it possible that sometimes the node that executes the query does not contain all the records and that's why sometimes some records are missing?

Comment: do you execute repairs regularly?

Comment: Not sure about this, but most probably no.

Comment: then it's possible that some data isn't distributed to all nodes, and when you read with `ONE` node that receives request don't have them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the consistency level of the query to `QUORUM` fixed the issue.